# Hiding and Showing dynamically generated listviews with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

We are building a jQuery Mobile app to be used with Phonegap. The content on a list is being generated by parsing an XML document and creating multiple listviews from it.

Each of these listviews is used for a different date range, I.E. Div #0 for May 1st 2013 to June 1st 2013, Div #1 for June 2nd 2013 to July 1st 2013.

The listviews are generating fine but the issue that happens is that once they are generated it appears to be impossible to hide and then show them again with jQuery's built in hide function.

On the page there is 4 divs with listviews in them, #list0 through #list4

No matter what i try (In Javascript Console or natively in the code) i can't get them to show once hidden, or as it is now with them all visible i can't get them to hide.

If you go directly to the page and not through jQuery Mobile's built in navigation system then the hiding and showing works fine. So i assume it obviously has something to do with their navigation system, but nothing i've tried or looked at seems to have any explanation or extra info.

If you have any suggestions i'd love to hear them! I've fiddled with this for hours and have got no where.

---

Dev URL: http://ferriesapp.ca/app/jqm/routes/horseshoebay/freeindex.html

Just click on Departure Bay to see the page that has the generated content.

Versions:

- jQuery Mobile Version 1.3.0
- jQuery Version 1.9.1
- Cordova Version 2.3.0

Comment: I'm using .css jQuery API and the list hide/show works like a charm for me.

Comment: Are you loading content dynamically though? Or just with static content?

Comment: I just used the firebug console on the dev link which you shared.

Comment: Are you going to the initial URL and then navigating to Departure Bay, then running it?

When i get to that point and then do

`$('#list0').css("display","none");`

Nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I understood what the problem here is, you have two div's with same IDs when you navigate from Horseshoebay to Departure Bay. So in order to hide/show, first you need to refer to the active page. Following is the code and I hope this works for you.

```
$("div.ui-page-active").find('#list1').css('display','none');
```